# Image not retrieving Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, file-storage

I am trying to retrieve the image. I didn't create the symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public by `php artisan storage:link` method. Rather than this, I added this code to `App::make('files')->link(storage_path('app/public'), public_path('storage'));` to `app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php`. But still no luck image is not showing and there is also no error.

Code in View:

```
<img src="/public/storage/{{$main->image_dir}}" /> // /public/storage/main/image.jpg
<img src="/storage/{{$main->image_dir}}" /> // /storage/main/image.jpg
<img src="http://localhost:8000/storage/{{$main->image_dir}}" /> // http://localhost:8000/storage/main/image.jpg
```

I am not getting image with any of above 3 links. Images are stored here: `storage/app/main`.

Comment: Hi, your question seems more like a google search than a question, don't you think?

Comment: @JuangaCovas Really? What makes you think so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I deleted the folder named `public` by mistake from `storage/app`. My images were stored in `storage/app/main`, in this case, images were not retrieving. Now it is stored in `storage/app/public/main` and it is working perfectly fine.